# Character encoding difference between source:retrieve vs mdapi:retrieve?

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx-cli

Here is the screenshot of a simple validation rule in Salesforce:

[image]

and I am now going to retrieve this validation rule using three different options and notice how the `'` (apostrophe) is escaped(or encoded).

**Option 1**: `'` (apostrophe) is encoded as `&apos;`

Retrieved using package.xml file on workbench:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <validationRules>
        <fullName>Tru_validation_rule</fullName>
        <active>true</active>
        <errorConditionFormula>OR( &apos;a&apos;&amp; &apos;b&apos; = &apos;ab&apos;)</errorConditionFormula>
        <errorMessage>Test</errorMessage>
    </validationRules>
</CustomObject>
```

**Option 2**:  `'` (apostrophe) is encoded as `&apos;`

Retrieved using package.xml with the command `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve --unpackaged=package.xml --retrievetargetdir=temp_folder --targetusername=dev`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <validationRules>
        <fullName>Tru_validation_rule</fullName>
        <active>true</active>
        <errorConditionFormula>OR( &apos;a&apos;&amp; &apos;b&apos; = &apos;ab&apos;)</errorConditionFormula>
        <errorMessage>Test</errorMessage>
    </validationRules>
</CustomObject>
```

**Option 3**:  `'` (apostrophe) is encoded as `&39;`

Retrieved using package.xml with the command `sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest=package.xml --targetusername=dev`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ValidationRule xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Tru_validation_rule</fullName>
    <active>true</active>
    <errorConditionFormula>OR( &#39;a&#39;&amp; &#39;b&#39; = &#39;ab&#39;,&#39;c&#39;&amp; &#39;d&#39; = &#39;cd&#39;,&#39;e&#39;&amp; &#39;f&#39; = &#39;ef&#39;, 1 = 1, 2= 2)</errorConditionFormula>
    <errorMessage>Test</errorMessage>
</ValidationRule>
```

Notice how option 3 is using different encoding of characters compared to Option 1 and 2. Why **Option 3** has different xml encoding(or character encoding) different compared to Option 1 and 2? Any insights on this?

We are a team of 5 developers spread across and each developer uses their own way of retrieving components from sandbox and this difference is causing unnecessary differences in Git.

Comment: Opened issue on sfdx github repo: https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/issues/181